# Proving that every circle in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ is the image of a circle on the Riemann Sphere under the Stereographic Projection.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that a circle in the complex plane is the image of a circle on the Riemann Sphere under the Stereographic Projection. So far, I have begun with the equation of an arbitrary circle in the plane $(x+a)^2 + (y+b)^2 = r^2$. Next, I use the definition of the stereographic projection $\phi=\left(\frac{x}{1-z}, \frac{y}{1-z},0\right)$ for $z\neq1$, plugging in the first two terms for $x$ and $y$ in the equation for a circle. After multiplying and simplifying, I am left with 
$$x^2+2ax-2axz+y^2+2by-2byz+(a^2+b^2-r^2)-2(a^2+b^2-r^2)z+(a^2+b^2-r^2)z^2 = 0.$$
I would obviously like to translate this into the equation of a plane with distance $<1$ from the origin, which would finish the proof; however, I can't for the life of me see where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Stereographic projection does nice things with circles, but the specific numbers are nasty. My preference is to show that stereographic projection is inversion in the sphere $S[(0, 0, 1); \sqrt{2}]$, and prove the circle-preserving properties of the sphere inversion map.